# number of solutions to a linear equation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let positive integers $a_1, a_2, \cdots ,a_n$ and $M$ be given.

How many nonnegative integer solutions $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ are there for the following equation:

$$a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2+\cdots +a_n x_n=M.$$

Comment: You may want to learn about Stars and Bars https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: It works for the case $a_1=a_2=\cdots a_n=1$.

Comment: Whether there are any solutions at all depends on $M$. This is related to the Frobenius coin problem. If $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n) \nmid M$, then there are no solutions.

Comment: And when there is a solution, there are infinitely many of them. You may want to see Theorem 2.3.3 in this document http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:530204/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the references.